# How to send bulk emails from within Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm planning on building an app that would have a Mongo collection of client information, including emails for each client. This wouldn't be a public app, but one for a select group of users within a company. I'd like the user to be able to query a selection of people from the database to send a bulk email. I'm aware that the Meteor email package can send individual transactional emails in response to actions. But how would bulk emails be done? Should they be off-loaded to a service like Mailgun? If so, how would that work within Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailgun is native to meteor with the Email package, however you are limited to 300 emails per day:

http://blog.mailgun.com/native-mailgun-integration-lets-meteor-apps-send-email/

Comment: Thank you. Just the info I was looking for.

Comment: This blog post has good info on wrapping the mailgun NPM package if you want to use your own mailgun credentials https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/wrapping-npm-packages/

Comment: Does the email package work only if deployed on Meteor's server? If I deployed on an EC2 instance, would it work?